# c++ openCV 3.1 - can't use Mat or most of the openCV things like in the tutorials

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

Best

I'm trying to create a project in C++, which relays most of the time on the 
**open-cv library**.

Therefore, I've installed **open-cv3.1.0** on my **windows** machine and connected the
**library** and **include** map/files to my **netbeans** c++ project.

---

### Succes

Overall I think that I've managed to do this correctly because
I don't receive any errors when I **compile**/**run** the application with the next piece of code in it.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
```

++ I can read an images in and visualize it :)

```
CvMat *img = cvLoadImageM(location.c_str(),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
cvWaitKey();
```

---

### Problem

**But** as soon as I take a random tutorial. E.g.

```
// create a big 8Mb matrix
Mat A(1000, 1000, CV_64F);
```

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/core/doc/intro.html

**Or even**

```
Mat A;
```

Then I get immediately an compile error :

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/ai4 build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/PrincipalComponentAnalysis.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/ReadInImage.o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o -L../../../netbeans/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc14/bin -lopencv_world310 -lopencv_world310d
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/PrincipalComponentAnalysis.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/cygdrive/d/fun/ai/ai4/../../../netbeans/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:571: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
...
```

---

The only things which doesn't give me an error are :

```
CvMat A;
CvMat *B;
IplImage *C;
IplImage D;
```

Which s***t because most (all) the tutorials, and stackoverflow issues are using the **Mat A**  or **cv::Mat A** version.

---

### Question

Thus the question : Did you've ever had the same kind of problem or issue? and are you willing to help me? + How can I solve it.

---

### edit : Configuration steps - OpenCV 3.1

Tools --> Options --> c/c++ --> Code Assistance :

- D:\netbeans\openCV\opencv\build\include
- D:\netbeans\openCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2

R-click Project --> Properties --> build --> C++ Compiler --> include directories

- ../../../netbeans/OpenCV/opencv/build/include
- ../../../netbeans/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2

R-click Project --> Properties --> build --> linker --> Additional Library Directories

- ../../../netbeans/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc14/bin

R-click Project --> Properties --> build --> linker --> Libraries --> Add Labrary

- opencv_world310
- opencv_world310d

---

### Solution

1. Download CMake
2. Download OpenCV
3. Download **MinGW** <-- Use this as compiler instead of **cygwin**
4. Install **MinGW**
5. Follow this link --> http://eyalarubas.com/opencv-installation-on-windows-netbeans-mingw.html

Comment: It seems you only have the C Api and I have no idea why.

Comment: Wait, you are compiling with cygwin and linking to the VC14 libs? That's obviously your error. VC14 is for MSVC14, you will need to compile OpenCV yourself to use cygwin

Comment: @GPPK - and how do you do that?

Comment: [using a tutorial](http://hvrl.ics.keio.ac.jp/kimura/opencv/opencv-3.1.0.html) - I have no idea if that particular one works but the general gist is use cmake to compile OpenCV

Comment: And please **don't** use obsolete C api!

Comment: @Miki what's interesting though is that the C API works at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are compiling with cygwin and linking to the VC14 libs.

That's your error. VC14 is for MSVC14 (Visual Studio Compiler), you will need to compile OpenCV yourself to use cygwin. OpenCV does not come with other pre-built libraries.

There are multiple tutorials online of how to do it but effectively you need to use cmake in order to compile OpenCV for your particular tool chain.

Comment: I've add a solution link

Answer (score 0):

You have problem while calling the destructor of `cv::Mat`. I faced this problem onced. It was related to mismatch between the library and the program. For example `64` and `32` ,`debug` and `release` or `mt` and `md` something like these. So, the first thing that you have to do is to make sure that everything are matched between OpenCV built and your calling program.

Comment: - i'll add my  configuration stepts